# preg_match_all regex Issue

Tags: php, regex

I am using `preg_match_all`, trying to match :

```
[<? or <?php]
[any amount of space here, at least one, may be newline]
[legendcool]
[any amount of space]
[(] return whatever is in here [)]
[any amount of space]
[?>]
```

I have this so far:

index.php

```
$the_prophecy = file_get_contents("secret.php");
preg_match_all('~[<?|<?php]\s*[legendcool(](.*?)[)]\s*[?>]~',$the_prophecy,$matches) ;
```

secret.php

```
<title>Regex Match all characters between two strings - Stack Overflow</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
<?php          legendcool({'',''})       ?>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/
```

For example, in secret.php, I would want to get `{'',''}`

Do any of you guys know how I can adjust my `preg_match_all` to work in the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of mistakes in your regex:

1. Square brackets should be replaced with round ones
2. `?` should be escaped since its a special meaning in regular expressions
3. flag `s` (DOTALL) needs to be used if you want to match new lines as well

A better regex can be like this:

```
~<\?(?:php)?(.+?)\?>~s
```

Using above suggestions your final solution would be:

```
preg_match_all('~<\?(?:php)?\s+legendcool\(([^)]+)\).*?\?>~s', $the_prophecy, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
// OUTPUT:  {'',''}
```

Comment: replaced with normal ones you mean? :)

Comment: cool regex, Do you know how can I match against `any amount of whitespace`? I read this works `\s*` but it doesnt seem to work with my regex

Comment: `\s*` should work for matching 0 or more spaces. You should rather use `\s+` for matching 1 or more space or tab or newline.

Comment: Hmm cool, I modified your regex, but i cant get it to match, what do you think Anubhava? `'~<\?(?:php)(\s+)?(.+?)\?>~s'`

Comment: Ok can you tell me what is your final regex now?

Comment: Oh this one, dude : '~<\?(?:php)(\s+)?(.+?)\?>~s'

Comment: Thanks also pls provide the the input string in your question so that I can test it.

Comment: Ok thanks, the test input that Im using is the secret.php in the description

Comment: My full regex is `'~[<?|<?php]\s*[legendcool(](.*?)[)]\s*[?>]~'`, but that has so many problems.. :(

Comment: So you're trying to match above regex on text from `secret.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to first direct you to the [PHP PCRE Cheat Sheet](https://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/190m/12sp/cheat-sheets/php-regex-cheat-sheet.pdf), which is a quick reference for all your regex needs in PHP.

Next, the use of `[` and `]` in regex is for character groups, and basically means "match any of these characters", for instance `[afd]` will match any of the characters `a`, `f` or `d`.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up brackets and parens `[<?|<?php]` should be `(<?|<?php)`. If you don't want it to capture anything, write `(?:<?|<?php)`.